# How do i add ObservableList obtained from Mysql server to javaFX Tableview?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to populate JavaFX tableview with the contents of a mysql database. I have created an observable list and added table data in it but i don't know how to display this list in tableview. Here is code for list,

```
public ObservableList<PatientDto> getAllPatientInfo() {
    ObservableList<PatientDto> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        String sql = "select * from patient_record";
        ps = DbUtil.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            PatientDto patientDto = new PatientDto();
            patientDto.setPid(rs.getInt("PID"));
            patientDto.setPatient_Name(rs.getString("Patient_Name"));
            patientDto.setAddress(rs.getString("Address"));
            patientDto.setAge(rs.getInt("Age"));
            patientDto.setDisease(rs.getString("Disease"));
            patientDto.setDoctor_Name(rs.getString("Doctor_Name"));
            patientDto.setAdmit_Date(rs.getDate("Admit_date"));
            patientDto.setDischarge_Date(rs.getDate("Discharge_Date"));
            list.add(patientDto);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

I am using scene builder for UI and this is interface of my tableview
[TableView In scene builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0vHF.png)

And this is ss of my table in mysql database. [Table in Mysql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XDFD.png).
I am newbie in JavaFX so i am finding it difficult to implement available answers. So please describe in detailed manner.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need a model class that holds the information for the table, lets call this as `PatientModel` that looks like this:

```
public class PatientModel {

private StringProperty pid;
private StringProperty patientName;
private StringProperty address;
/* ...
 * and so on...
 */

public PatientModel(String pid, String patientName, String address) {
    this.pid = new SimpleStringProperty(pid);
    this.patientName = new SimpleStringProperty(patientName);
    this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
}

public String getPid() {
    return pid.get();
}

public StringProperty pidProperty() {
    return pid;
}

public String getPatientName() {
    return patientName.get();
}

public StringProperty patientNameProperty() {
    return patientName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address.get();
}

public StringProperty addressProperty() {
    return address;
}
}
```

Then you need an `.fxml` file that similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.91"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="stackoverflow.TestController">
    <TableView fx:id="table">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="pidColumn" text="PID"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" text="Patient Name"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="addressColumn" text="Address"/>
            <!-- and so on... -->
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

Then a controller class:

```
public class TestController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView<PatientModel> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PatientModel, String> pidColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PatientModel, String> nameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PatientModel, String> addressColumn;

private ObservableList<PatientModel> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    initTable();
    // if the data is coming from an other class you have probably a list of them,
    // if not you can simply populate the tableData
    List<PatientDto> dtosFromDB = new ArrayList<>();
    tableData.addAll(dtosFromDB.stream().map(this::convertDtoToModel).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

private void initTable() {
    table.setItems(tableData);

    pidColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().pidProperty()); // here is where tha magic happens :)

    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().patientNameProperty()); // this sets the cells value from
                                                                                   // the model.
    addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().addressProperty());
}

private PatientModel convertDtoToModel(PatientDto dto) {
    return new PatientModel(dto.getPid().toString(), dto.getName(), dto.getAddress()/* and so on */);
}
}
```

After you have these classes you can simply load the `.fxml` from your main class, then you have to complete with all of the informations and it should work.

P.S. Sorry for the indenting, I cannot indent here the whole code just by rows and it is so boring.

Comment: I also have a sql date obtained from datepicker, how do i bind date in Stringproperty?

Comment: did you assume this List dtosfromDB holds all data from database?

Comment: As I know javafx don't have a built in DatePickerTableCell, but you can write one. This is a mapping stuff, you have to write some converter methods/classes, then you can use it as you wish.